# Using the PayPal _cart system, but need to be able to limit shipping to UK addresses only

Tags: paypal

We're using the PayPal _cart system, but need to be able to limit shipping to UK addresses only. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much chasing, I've now had an answer direct from PayPal... apparently, this isn't possible any more.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that provides instructions from a PayPal forum moderator:

https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Shipping/I-don-t-want-to-accept-International-orders/td-p/183580

As the recommendations in that link suggest, you can go to "Managing My Risk", and there is a part that allows you to deny payments from a list of countries that you can specify.  You can move all countries to the deny side with that option.  Be sure to leave your country in the left, "unmonitored" column, so the right column would have all countries except yours.

In your account settings you can limit to purchases from only those with a PayPal account from your same country.  Another option would be to put a ridiculous shipping charge on any international orders to discourage anyone from making a purchase outside the country.  These may be overkill, but it might not hurt to do them just in case.